# Please provide assistance with PHP login script

Tags: php, mysql

I'm new at creating login scripts with php and MySQL and was hoping for some help.  I've already gotten the basics down for actually checking that the entered information is correct and I've gotten the sessions to work correctly.  However, I'm having trouble getting the user's info to pull from his/her row and displaying on the membership page.  Do I need to do another query and add a while loop within this page to collect the information?  Here are the scripts:

**login.php**

```
$p_num = "";
    $pwd = "";
    $errors = "";
    $num_rows = 0;

    $user_id = "";
    $user_name = "";
    $password = "";
    $image = "";
    $user_email = "";
    $program = "";

    if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST"){
        include("database.php");
        $p_num = $_POST["username"];
        $pwd = $_POST["password"];

        $query = "SELECT * FROM $user_table WHERE user_id = '$p_num' AND password = '$pwd'";
        $result = mysqli_query($connect, $query);
        $num_rows = mysqli_num_rows($result);

        if($result){
            echo "There is/are  " .$num_rows ." set(s) in the database with this info.<br>";
            if($num_rows > 0){
                session_start();
                $_SESSION["login"] = 1;
                header("Location: ../pages/instructor.php");
            }
            else{
                echo "Unable to login";
            }
        }
    }
```

**instructor.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<?php
    include("../php/login.php");
    include("../php/database.php");
?>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"> 
        <title></title>
        <link href="../css/style.css" rel="stylesheet/less" type="text/css">
        <script src="../js/jquery.2.0.3.js"></script>
        <script src="../js/script.js"></script>
        <script src="../js/less-1.7.4.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="page">
            <header>
                <div id="logo" class="logo_bg"></div>
                <div id="fsi_logo" class="logo_bg"></div>
            </header>

            <div id="main">
                <?php
                    session_start();
                    if(isset($_SESSION["login"])){
                        echo "Hello";
                    }
                ?>
                <div id="bleg">
                    <h1><a href="../pages/create_scenario.html">BUILD SCENARIO</a></h1>
                    <h1><a href="#">SEARCH SCENARIOS</a></h1>
                    <h1><a href="#">VIEW SCENARIOS</a></h1>
                </div>
            </div>

            <footer>Copyright&copy; 2014 FlightSafety International</footer>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**database.php**

```
$db = "spartan";
    $host = "localhost";
    $user = "root";
    $password = "";
    $connect = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $password) or die(mysqli_error($connect));
    $user_table = "users";
    $user_info = "user_info";

    $create_db_spartan = "CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS $db";
    $create_table_users = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS $user_table(user_id VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL, user_name VARCHAR(100), password VARCHAR(16), PRIMARY KEY(user_id))";
    $create_table_users_info = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS $user_info(user_id VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL, user_name VARCHAR(100), email VARCHAR(50), program VARCHAR(4), PRIMARY KEY(user_name))";

    mysqli_query($connect, $create_db_spartan) or die(mysqli_error($connect));
    mysqli_select_db($connect, $db) or die(mysqli_error($connect));
    mysqli_query($connect, $create_table_users) or die(mysqli_error($connect));
    mysqli_query($connect, $create_table_users_info) or die(mysqli_error($connect));
```

Just as an FYI, I am not concerned with SQL Injection at this point in time, this isn't something that's been released and it's on an internal network.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: To display data from DB, yes use a `while` loop. `while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){  echo $row['column_you_want_to_echo'];}`

Comment: @Fred, I tried that, however, even with the include statement, It's kicking back an error stating that the variable $result isn't indexed.  Any suggestions for how to fix this?

Comment: @Fred-ii- Why not `mysqli_fetch_assoc`? Plus it's better to use the OOP Way. :)

Comment: @Robert Where is `$user_table` being defined?

Comment: @Brad, as of right now, I am the only person that has access to this.  I'll handle SQL Injection at a later point.  Please provide feedback on the question if you have any.

Comment: @iFarbod OP can choose either/or. There are many ways to fetch/display date.

Comment: @Fredi, it's being defined inside the database.php file.  I'll add that code to the question.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Sorry for that, i love this way :) - anyway, i'm still a newbie and i always want to learn.

Comment: @Robert Far as I can tell, my suggestion should work, it's a common method or `mysqli_fetch_assoc()`. The only reason I can think of that it's not working for you is that your form elements are not named or you didn't use the loop in the right place. Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening `<?php` tag 
`error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` see if it yields anything if you're not already doing so. Plus, `or die(mysqli_error($connect))` to `mysqli_query()`

Comment: Try using `var_dump()` or [Kint](http://raveren.github.io/kint/) to log it, then give us results.

Comment: `string '' (length=0)` is what I'm getting doing a var_dump();

Comment: @Fred, I'm not getting any errors.

Comment: Your method of `$num_rows = mysqli_num_rows($result);` ... `if($result){` ... `if($num_rows > 0){` is off. You're best just doing `$num_rows = mysqli_num_rows($result); if($num_rows > 0){ echo "There is/are  " .$num_rows...`

Comment: @Fred, ok, got that changed.

Comment: @Robert I suggest you take it up with the people who have given "answers" below. My commenting is taking up too much room already. They're the ones who need to work for their points. ;)

Comment: @Robert This is what Brad talked about: [**`mysqli` with prepared statements**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php), or [**PDO with prepared statements**](http://php.net/pdo.prepared-statements).

Comment: @Fred, thank's for the reference, but I honestly don't care anymore.  I've given up on trying to get an actual answer.  Thanks for the assistance though.

Comment: You're welcome. If I may suggest Robert; try a simpler query using barebones PHP, no fancy stuff like JS. Once you've successfully queried, only then should you start adding sessions variables. If one session variable works, then you can move on to the next step of assigning another. Good luck.

Comment: @halfer Yeah, I've given up on getting an answer to my question.  Your answer helped a little.  Thanks for the assistance.

Comment: Alright, though I can't see why you are giving up so soon. I see that some comments have been deleted above, so I guess that someone said something a little bit too sharp. If so, it's worth bearing in mind that Stack Overflow can be a touch spiky at times - just don the bulletproof vest, ignore unhelpful comments, flag them if necessary, and move on `:)`.

Comment: @halfer, it's been a very long day also, so the unhelpful and unproductive comments didn't help.  Thanks for the advice though.

Comment: I actually figured out how to do what I needed to do this morning.  Thanks for helping everyone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In both of your scripts, `session_start()` is issued after data has been sent to the browser. This means that the opportunity for setting headers has passed, and so session cookies cannot be set. Thus, sessions will not work.

In both cases, put this command at the top of your script, or at least before the opening `DOCTYPE`. Your sessions should then start working.

Similarly, your `header('Location: X')` needs to be used prior to output being sent, otherwise the redirect will not work. However this appears just after an `echo` and the output of the `DOCTYPE`. Remove the echo and then edit the start of your instructor.php file thus:

```
<?php
    include("../php/login.php");
    include("../php/database.php");
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

Here the output of the `DOCTYPE` should not happen until the loading of files and initialisation is complete. If there is any cookies/sessions/redirects to do, they can be done here.

All of these 'headers already sent' issues should raise a warning. If you are not seeing this in your development environment, you may have on-screen errors disabled - make sure they are turned on.